# Getting reducer is not a function error when I click Add to basket button

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am currently building an amazon clone.

Hello every time I click the add to cart button react displays:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/73H9W.png)

StateProvider

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
```

```
// Prepares the dataLayerexport const StateContext = createContext();
```

```
// Wrap our app and provide the Data layerexport const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children }) => (<StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>{children}</StateContext.Provider>);
```

```
// Pull information from the data layerexport const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

reducer

```
export const initialState = {
  basket: [],
  user: null
};

// Selector
export const getBasketTotal = (basket) => 
  basket?.reduce((amount, item) => item.price + amount, 0);

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  console.log(action);
  switch (action.type) {
    case "ADD_TO_BASKET":
      return {
        ...state,
        basket: [...state.basket, action.item],
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default reducer;
```

product

```
import React from 'react'
import "./Product.css"
import { useStateValue } from './StateProvider'

function Product({id, title, image, price, rating}) {
        const [{basket}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

        const addToBasket = () =>{
            //dispatch the item into the data layer
            dispatch({
                type: "ADD_TO_BASKET",
                item: {
                    
                    title: title,
                    image: image,
                    price: price,
                    rating: rating,
                },
            });

        };
    return (
    <div className = "product">
        <div className='product_info'>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p className= "product_price">
                <small>$</small>
                <strong>{price}</strong>
            </p>


        </div>

        <img src={image}></img>

        <div className='product_rating'>
                {Array(rating).fill().map((_, i)=> (
                    <p>⭐</p>
                ))}
            </div>

        <button onClick={addToBasket}>Add to Basket</button>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Product
```

stateprovider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";
// Prepares the dataLayer
export const StateContext = createContext();

// Wrap our app and provide the Data layer
export const StateProvider = ({reducer, initialState, children }) => (
  <StateContext.Provider value={useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
    {children}
  </StateContext.Provider>
);

// Pull information from the data layer
export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

When I click the button it should display the props in the console and send the data to store but instead it just displays an error message. I read some previously asked questions and someone pointed out that it may be because I am running babel? Any help would be much appreciate

Answer (score 0):

The `reducer` variable being passed to `useReducer` is actually destructured from the `StateProvider` props. You haven't shown us the code that renders `StateProvider`, but I imagine it does not specify a `reducer` prop, and thus is `undefined`, which is indeed not a function.

Rather than making `reducer` a prop, define the `reducer` function at the same level as you define `StateProvider`. The variable will still be in scope, but not treated as React state, alleviating a few issues that treating it as such will cause.

I would also suggest following the React documentation more closely. The patterns used are employed widely and often avoid confusion and common pitfalls. For example, it's generally not a great idea to call hooks from within the return/JSX since it's trivially easy to accidentally wind up making them conditional or changing the order which will introduce bugs.

Comment: I edited the post to include stateprovider.js

Comment: @TylerEwing You aren't showing where you are rendering it, just the definition, which you already shared (and I used to form my answer).